# How to return values in array of json using laravel query?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

```
$search='m';
$data = Product::select("product_name")
        ->where('product_name','LIKE', '%' . $search . '%')
        ->get();
    
 return response()->json($data);
```

It returns

```
[{"product_name":"MyProduct"},{"product_name":"MAC"}] .....
```

But I want [{"MyProduct"},{"MAC"}]

Comment: `return response()->json([$data]);` it is better to work with [resources](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources)

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid `JSON`. JSON objects eg. `{}` need keys to work.

```
[{"MyProduct"},{"MAC"}]
```

I assume you want to have an array of strings.

```
["MyProduct", "MAC"]
```

Use pluck to get model properties as an array. Which will return the array of strings.

```
return response()->json($data->pluck('product_name'));
```

Comment: I would always prefer to use object, not would fit into the code smell Primitive Obsession https://medium.com/the-sixt-india-blog/primitive-obsession-code-smell-that-hurt-people-the-most-5cbdd70496e9